# How can I get event from element that dynamically added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating input field dynamically in my page with some id like `#MyField` And when I try to catch click event by `$('#MyField').click(function (){})` it doesn't work!
Am I do it in wrong way?

Comment: try this `$('#MyField').on("click", function (){})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment: define doesn't work.

Comment: @PankajMakwana: That's just the long form of the shortcut form the OP used, it's functionally identical.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see the comment from Sujith

Comment: @Sujith well seen! I learned something today.

Comment: @SumiStraessle: I already closed this as a dupe of the *previous* question that that one should have been closed as a dupe of (and now has been).

Comment: try this `$(document).on("click", '#MyField', function (){})`